# iPhone localization not working in an iPad project just converted into universal one

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, storyboard

I'm developing an iPad application (base English) + Italian localization. 
Now I've just edited this project and it's universal (both iPad and iPhone). I've added the iPhone storyboard and everything's fine except the translation. I deleted the Italian localization and repeated the procedure. Now this is the situation:

Main_iPhone.storyboard
Main_iPhone.strings (Italian)

Main_iPad.storyboard
Main_iPad.strings (Italian)

The iPad translation still works perfectly but the iPhone one does not. It's always English (base) even if I set the Italian language. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you did this or not, but you can't copy the contents from one .strings file to the other when working with NIBs or storyboards. The object identifiers (like `EI2-c9-dhD`) are different for each interface file, so you can only copy and paste the actual translations for each individual string.

Comment: Hi Scott, when i added the iPhone storyboard i copied the iPad one into it, all the identifiers are equal so the two .strings files are equal...

Comment: I mean that every graphic object in one storyboard (for example a button) has the same identifier of the corresponding button in the other storyboard

Comment: In the string files the identifiers may be equal, but they are not in the actual storyboard. The iPhone strings file now has objects with identifiers that don't exist in the iPhone storyboard (only in the iPad storyboard).

Comment: Even if i go over one IBOutlet on the code the corresponding graphic object in the iPhone and iPad storyboards highlight because they have the same identifier. So even if they have the same identifiers, are they different? Should i create a brand new storyboard from the beginning equal to the iPad one with different components and identifiers for each graphic component? It seems strange

Comment: @yell0wn: Please add a screenshot of the identifiers of two objects that represent the same thing in both storyboards. For example, a screenshot of the identifier of a button in the iPhone storyboard, and a screenshot of the same button in the iPad storyboard.

Comment: I can't, i don't have enough reputation :( Anyway, in my project every ViewController in the iPad storyboard is equal to the corresponding one in the iPhone storyboard, only the sizes changes of course. And every graphic object is equal to the corresponding one in the iPhone storyboard. Every component id matches the corresponding one in the other storyboard, there are no differences.

Comment: I need reputation 10 to post images, i only have 6. As soon as I reach 10, I will post the screenshots

Comment: For example: /* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Panel"; ObjectID = "8GE-YI-18V"; */
"8GE-YI-18V.text" = "Pannello"; has the same identifier both in the iPad and iPhone storyboard, related to the same  view controller in the code. This item is in the Main_iPhone.strings and in the Main_iPad.strings but when running the simulator only the iPad translation works, the iPhone one is ignored

Comment: Problem solved. I first created a Main_iPhone.storyboard on the root folder. After that I repeated the localization procedure, then I deleted the Main_Iphone.storyboard and put a copy of that into the Base.lproj…and I think that drove Xcode crazy. Even if the iPhone part ran perfectly, it was using a "ghost" storyboard which I deleted. So I restored an old version of the project and did it all through Xcode, now  it's ok.